# Saving and reading user setting in app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I have this app.config :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
 <configSections>
<sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
  <section name="Alvaro1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="conexx" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.2 ;Initial Catalog =ifdcontroladoria3 ;uid =sa;pwd = admin2012" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/></startup>
<userSettings>
<Alvaro1.Properties.Settings>
   <setting name="servidor" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="banco" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="user" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="senha" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
</Alvaro1.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

I have set system.configuration in the header and in reference, and use this code to save values :

```
   Properties.Settings.Default.servidor = comboBox1.Text;
   Properties.Settings.Default.banco = cmbBancos.Text;
```

but when i try to read these values , nothing is saved :

```
        servidor = Properties.Settings.Default.servidor;
        banco = Properties.Settings.Default.banco;
        lblLevanta.Text = servidor + " " + banco;
```

What i m doing wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be that you are not calling the `Save` method to actually persist the values into the configuration file.

After you set the values of the settings, try using:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

It's also worth noting that if you are debugging\running in Visual Studio, the config file will get overwritten each time you perform a new build - so updated settings won't be preserved between runs of the application.

Comment: (+1) *It's also worth noting that if you are debugging\running in Visual Studio, the config file will get overwritten each time you perform a new build - so updated settings won't be preserved between runs of the application.*